# How to merge the following array structure into one array, showing only the results

Tags: php, sql, arrays, doctrine

I have this weird array output after I execute a query and it looks like this

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "key" => "overview.domain"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "key" => "overview.msg_latest_translation"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "key" => "overview.no_stats"
  ]
```

But all i want it to be only one array, not a nested array.
SO it would look something like this

```
array:32 [▼
  "overview.domain",
  "overview.msg_latest_translation",
  "overview.no_stats"
]
```

What would be the best way to solve this ?

This is the query that i am executing, which is giving me the first output:

```
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.key')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this ([PHP array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)):

```php
$rows = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.key')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    
$arr = array_map(function($_v){return $_v['key'];}, $rows);
```

With `array_map` you can change the values of the array by its value.